# IntelliJ and AngularCLI 6 - import library by package name

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-cli, webstorm, angular-cli-v6

I have an Angular CLI 6 project, with contains 2 components:

- a library with services/components
- a project which uses this library

When I want to use the library in the frontend project, I should use for example:

```
import { SomeLibModule } from "some-lib";
```

Instead, with IntelliJ, when I'm using auto-import feature (i.e. I'm typing `SomeLibModule` and I'm hitting Alt + Enter), the specified import is:

```
import {SomeLibModule} from '../../projects/some-lib/src/lib/some-lib.module';
```

How can I change this behavior to prefer imports using their package name?

Here a simple repository to reproduce this behavior : https://github.com/lbar/ngcli-with-lib (the library import is in `app.module.ts`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding one more path mapping to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
      "some-lib": [
        "dist/some-lib",
        "projects/some-lib/src/lib/some-lib.module"
      ],
      "some-lib/*": [
        "dist/some-lib/*"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion: it works well when I'm in the project that uses the packaged library. But there is a side effect: when I'm in the library itself, the imports should not be `"some-lib"`.

Comment: If I moved the code you suggest in the `tsconfig.app.json` of the client project, the import are correct in the project and in the library. It is just annoying to repeat this in each client project but if I have no choice...

Comment: you need to somehow let the IDE know that your local module has to be imported as if it's a published node module; seems specifying path mappings in tsconfig is the only way to do this